# Загрузка контента при прокрутке страницы.

Tags: веб-программирование, ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть такой скрипт.

```
var bSuppressScroll = false;

$(document).ready(
function()
{
function last_msg_funtion()
{
var ID=$(".message_box:last").attr("id");

 $('div#last_msg_loader').html('<img src="../background/ajax-load.gif">');

$.post("stena/load_post.php?id=<?=$myrow[id]?>?action=get&last_msg_id="+ID,

function( data )
{
if (data != "") 
{
$(".message_box:last").after(data); 
window.bSuppressScroll = false;
}

$('div#last_msg_loader').empty();
$('div#last_msg_loader').hide();
} );
};

$(window).scroll(function(){
if ( ( $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() ) && window.bSuppressScroll == false ){
last_msg_funtion();
window.bSuppressScroll = true;
}
}); 
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать, например, если больше нет записей, то больше не обращаться при прокрутке и вывести сообщение, что записей больше нет. Просто в ajax еще не очень разбираюсь. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В скрипте-обработчике повесить условие - "если запись была крайней - вернуть то-то".
2. В ajax при подгрузке проверять наличие этого самого "то-то", если есть - выводим сообщение о том, что записи кончились.

Здесь дело не в ajax вообще, в принципе.

Comment: @Виталий RS, просто вот у меня, если закончились записи, то все равно идет обработчик, ищет записи, если нет, то не грузит, а если есть, то грузит. Тем самым нагружает сервер. А так у меня стоит проверка, если нет записей, то вывести на экран нет записей, но подзагрузка все равно идет постоянно.

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev, кешируйте, значит, информацию, и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @Виталий RS, спасибо большое.